# How to use the attribute : save() in views.py?

Tags: django, django-views

**
When I use the attribute save() in views.py the page gets this error :
NOT NULL constraint failed: pages_login.username

```
# views.py  :
    def about(request):
        username = request.POST.get("username")
        password = request.POST.get("password")
        data = Login(username=username,password=password)
        data.save()
        return render(request, 'pages/about.html')
# models.py :

    class Login(models.Model):
        username=models.CharField(max_length=40)
        password=models.CharField(max_length=40)
```

**

Comment: The issue could most probably be with the values of username or password have you checked their values ? are any of them empty ?

Answer (score 0):

```
Login(username=username,password=password)
```

This code will automatically insert the data to db. Please check your database. Or else you can save like this

```
data = Login()
data.username = username
data.password = password
data.save()
```

*Always save password as hashed form for security*

Comment: Thank you, but it still gets the error. where can I check my database ?

Comment: Is Login() a model class ?

Comment: Yes it is. 
class Login(models.Model):
    username=models.CharField(max_length=40)
    password=models.CharField(max_length=40)

Comment: so the datas are saved in login table in data base. also you can refer this document https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/default/#how-to-log-a-user-in

Comment: Also print username and password for ensure the data are getting

Comment: I  printed username and password  for ensure the data are getting and it saved the data I saw in powershell , but the page gets error when I put data.save()

Comment: Is there any other fields in Login(models.Model): ?

Comment: no . And there is a strange thing , when I open the page the first time it opened and everything is OK. but when I continue with the testing the pages it give this error. another strange thing I test add this code ( request.POST.get("username")  ) the page opened with no error, and when I continue testing the program it give the error again.

Answer (score 0):

is this the login view? no need to save you just have to redirect user after authenticating him

Comment: No, it just a name. I do the same code from a vedio ,but I get this error.

Comment: then maybe you aren't getting username in your request. print(request.POST) and verify please

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the code without getting the error,and the problem was solved. instead of data.save() I put :

```
if request.POST.get("username") :
    data.save()
```

I get the solution : instead of last code enter :

```
if request.method == "post" :
    data.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
username = request.POST.get("username")
password = request.POST.get("password")

Login.objects.create(username=username, password=password)
```

This statement will create and save object in single step.

Comment: Sorry, but it gets the same error.